# Register more than one hotkey with RegisterHotKey

Tags: c#, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I found this little piece of code to register an hotkey:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
            MessageBox.Show("Hotkey pressed");
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Alt + A
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, this.GetType().GetHashCode(), 1, (int)'A');
    }
```

It works perfectly, but my problem is I want to use two different shortcuts. I know the second parameter is the id, so I figure I could make a different id and add a new if statement in the WndProc function but I'm not sure how I would go about that.

In short, how would I go about creating a second shortcut?

Thanks,

Comment: `GetHashCode()` as ID is broken in two ways. 1) Two types can have the same hash 2) It uses the wrong range. "An application must specify an id value in the range 0x0000 through 0xBFFF. A shared DLL must specify a value in the range 0xC000 through 0xFFFF (the range returned by the GlobalAddAtom function). To avoid conflicts with hot-key identifiers defined by other shared DLLs, a DLL should use the GlobalAddAtom function to obtain the hot-key identifier."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, this.GetType().GetHashCode(), 1, (int)'A')
```

Don't use GetHashCode() here.  Just number your hot keys, start at 0.  There isn't any danger of getting the ids mixed up, hot key ids are specific for each Handle.  You'll get the *id* back in the WndProc() method.  Use m.WParam.ToInt32() to get the value:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312) {    // Trap WM_HOTKEY
        int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hotkey #{0} pressed", id));
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Missing closing-bracket in "Mbox.Show" line - can`t edit as I need 6 edited chars ~.~