# Register hotkeys in .NET - combination of three/four keys

Tags: c#, .net, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I got stuck.

Right now, I am using the following code to listen to hotkeys:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd,
      int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        {
            // whatever i need
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

and this function to register hotkey:

```
Form1.RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, this.GetType().GetHashCode(), 0, (int)chr);
```

it works perfectly.
my question is how do I register multiple hotkeys as the same combination, for example:

1. A+B+C+D
2. ALT+SHIFT+B
3. CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+X

edit: I found out (like Zooba said) how to "decrypt" which hotkey was sent and here's the solution:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        {
            Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
            ModifierKeys modifier = (ModifierKeys)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);
            if ((modifier + "+" + key == "Alt+S"))
            {
                //do what ever I need.
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Why not be a bit more ambitious and go for 5 or 6 key combinations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register more than one hotkey with RegisterHotKey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704134/register-more-than-one-hotkey-with-registerhotkey)

Comment: @David Heffernan, I would go for 5 or 6 key combination but windows doesnt allow to click on more than 4 keys at the same time :P. anyway, I just want to cover all the options...

Comment: @Ron Windows is just so lame!!!  ;-)

Comment: @David Heffernan, @Ron Pretty sure this limitation of the hardware not a windows issue ;)

Comment: @David Heffernan, Indeed windows is lame but what can I do? most of the games support only windows and I am a gamer..
@MerickOWA, I dont really care since no one will use more than 4 keys as combination (its hard to press).

Comment: @Ron Actually I was being sarcastic! For what it's worth I think Windows is awesome.

Comment: @David Heffernan, But I wasnt sarcastic.. linux is way much better than windows, but as I said, most of the games support only windows. Lets not continue this conversation because its not related to my question, thank you and sorry.

Comment: You still have that `GetHashCode` nonsense in there. I already explained in the question Hans linked why that's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of using `registerhotkey`, I used `KeyState` and it solved all my problems. If anyone is interested, you can [go here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library?msg=3644157) ([backup on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20151007163753/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library?msg=3644157))

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the link (and created and added a fresh archive.org link for the future).

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation for [WM_HOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> *lParam* The low-order word specifies the keys that were to be pressed in combination with the key specified by the high-order word to generate the WM_HOTKEY message. This word can be one or more of the following values. The high-order word specifies the virtual key code of the hot key.

So you can read the `LParam` member of `m` to determine the keys that were pressed (alternatively, if you assign more sensible identifiers than `GetHashCode` you can check `WParam`).

The 'high-order word' and 'low-order word' refer to parts of the integer (actually an `IntPtr`) contained in `LParam`, so you will need to extract these. The low-order word is  `i & 0xFFFF`, while the high-order word is `(i >> 16) & 0xFFFF`.

To detect which key combination was pressed, check the lowest four bits of the low-order word for the modifiers (shift, alt, control) and compare the high-order word against the virtual key code - which for letters is equal to the character value of the capital (for example, the virtual key code for A is (int)'A', but not (int)'a').

Your 'A+B+C+D' combination is not valid, since `WM_HOTKEY` hotkeys only support a single character. You will need to attach a keyboard hook to detect that combination from anywhere (or handle messages if you only want to detect it while your application is active).

Comment: if I need to attach a keyboard hook to detect combination that has more than 1 character then I have no use in this "hooker" at all.. I already got keyboard hooker which I wanted to abandon because it slowed down my program when I tried to close it. anyway, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: how do you know how to extract the low and high order words respectively using those bitwise operators? want to learn more, thanks.