# Detecting keystrokes while program is running in background

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, background, keystrokes

I am trying to create a small C# program using Visual Studio that simulates "Autofire" or "continuous clicking" for Afk monster-grinding on my Minecraft server.

The program works, or works when the program is in "foreground". I can start and stop the thread that handles the auto-clicking with a chosen button combination(Ctrl+Alt+Z).

But when the program is in the background(and the game in the foreground)i cannot start/stop the auto-clicking. The program simply do not register the button combination.

How do make the program register the button combination while it is in the background?

Comment: You probably need to register a hot key, check around, here is a link to start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752204/register-hotkeys-in-net-combination-of-three-four-keys

Comment: You did not say what mechanism you use for your bot's input faking. It's no fun guessing.

Comment: Ty for the answers, i am not sure how to get the code in TheGreatCOs link to work, but i will try to study it abit more :)

Comment: @David Heffernan, i used a simple form1_keyDown event, works great in foreground.