# How does this bitmask apply to LParam (WM_HOTKEY)

Tags: c#, winapi, bit-manipulation, intptr

Currently I am working on a simple class library to handle [global hot keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2c51t2b.aspx) with the help of various [blog posts](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207) and [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752288/2015959).

Consider this integral segment of code that I have put together.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

    if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        var modifier = (int) m.LParam & 0xFFFF;
        var key = ((int) m.LParam & 0xFFFF);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Something that I really do not understand and would like explained how the bitmask works here. I have a reasonable understanding of how to apply bitwise operators but I do not understand why this specific bitmask is being applied here.

Additionally, I am struggling to understand the purpose of `IntPtr`. Why is `LParam` and `IntPtr` in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `WM_HOTKEY` says that the `LPARAM` contains two 16 bit fields.  The high word (higher 16 bits) has the VK of the key pressed, and the low word (lower 16 bits) has the modifiers specified.

`LPARAM & 0xffff` will get the low 16 bits, and `LPARAM >> 16` will get the high 16 bits.

`LPARAM & 0xffff` works because the 32 bit LPARAM looks like:

```
   V bit 31                              V bit 0
   HIGH WORD           LOW WORD
0y vvvv vvvv vvvv vvvv mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm where v is the vk, and m is the modifier 
0y 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 == 0x0000ffff
========================================== Bitwise and
0y 0000 0000 0000 0000 mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm Just left with the modifier bits
```

`LPARAM >> 16` works by shifting the bits 16 positions to the right

```
   V bit 31                              V bit 0
   HIGH WORD           LOW WORD
0y vvvv vvvv vvvv vvvv mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm where v is the vk, and m is the modifier 
0y 0vvv vvvv vvvv vvvv vmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm right shifted once (>> 1)
0y 00vv vvvv vvvv vvvv vvmm mmmm mmmm mmmm right shifted twice (>> 2)
...
0y 0000 0000 0000 0000 vvvv vvvv vvvv vvvv right shifted sixteen times (>> 16)
```

`LPARAM` is defined as the size of a pointer, so it would map to an `IntPtr` in managed code.  Since we only use the low 32 bits of the LPARAM, we need to chop of the high 32.  We can cast to `int` to do so, but if you are running with `checked` arithmetic, it will result in an `OverflowException`.  Instead, we cast the `IntPtr` to a `long` (which on a 32 bit machine will zero fill) then to a `int` (which will truncate).

If we do not resize the `IntPtr` to a `Int32`, you could get exceptions if an application were to send a message with high bits set as the result of the `lparam >> 16`.

```
IntPtr lparam = /* comes from WndProc */;
Int32 lparam32 = unchecked((int)(long)lparam);

Int16 lowWord = lparam32 & 0xffff;
Int16 highWord = lparam32 >> 16;
```

That being said, here is a full implementation of a hotkey listener in C# that I can't remember where I found.  If anyone has attribution for this, please let me know, or edit this post to list the original author.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public sealed class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    private int _currentId;
    private Window _window;

    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

    public KeyboardHook()
    {
        EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> handler = null;
        this._window = new Window();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            handler = delegate (object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs args) {
                if (this.KeyPressed != null)
                {
                    this.KeyPressed(this, args);
                }
            };
        }
        this._window.KeyPressed += handler;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        for (int i = this._currentId; i > 0; i--)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(this._window.Handle, i);
        }
        this._window.Dispose();
    }

    public void RegisterHotKey(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key)
    {
        this._currentId++;
        if (!RegisterHotKey(this._window.Handle, this._currentId, (uint) modifier, (uint) key))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn’t register the hot key.");
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private class Window : NativeWindow, IDisposable
    {
        private static int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;

        public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

        public Window()
        {
            this.CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.DestroyHandle();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
            {
                Keys key = ((Keys) (((int) m.LParam) >> 0x10)) & Keys.KeyCode;
                ModifierKeys modifier = ((ModifierKeys) ((int) m.LParam)) & ((ModifierKeys) 0xffff);
                if (this.KeyPressed != null)
                {
                    this.KeyPressed(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(modifier, key));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```