# C# Custom paste like feature

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a way or inserting text anywhere on the system in Windows, much like the clipboard works. For example, pressing ctrl+shift+1 would 'paste' text set in my application into where the user is currently pointing the cursor.

For example, if my application sets it to be 'local.network' and the user presses ctrl+shift+1 in their browser address bar, it would paste in 'local.network'. I then want to have different values set, depending on what number the user presses. Is this possible or can I not create a system wide function like this?

Comment: You can use the Clipboard class to store things, don't know about detecting shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is how to register a hotkey.

[Register more than one hotkey with RegisterHotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704134/register-more-than-one-hotkey-with-registerhotkey)

[Set global hotkeys using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp)

**in response to your followup comment,** sorry, I though the question was more about the capturing the key press event.  If you need to paste text to a window that you don't own, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539187/insert-text-into-the-textbox-of-another-application) would be a near duplicate. That question uses `WM_SETTEXT` but you can easily use `WM_PASTE` instead.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I am after for detecting the key press. How would I go about 'pasting' the string to where the user is?